# Accessing Key:Value pairs in Matlab

Tags: database, matlab, key, query-builder

I have successfully created a db in Matlab using the Visual Query builder (database toolbox).  I am familiar with SQL and accessing key:value pairs with php and other languages, however I can't find the syntax anywhere for Matlab.  The code I have so far is:

```
conn = database('antoine_db','','');
c = catalogs(conn);
T = tables(conn);
cols = columns(conn);


sql_query = 'SELECT Formula,"Compound Name",A,B,C,TMIN,TMAX FROM antoine_data WHERE ID = 1'; 

result = fetch(conn,sql_query);
```

If 'result' here is a single row of data with multiple columns, how can I most easily access the data from a specific column?  I can already do it by using the column index, such as result(1,1).  What is the syntax in Matlab so I could access it by the column's name, such as result['Name']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the return format to a structure:

```
setdbprefs('datareturnformat','structure');
result = fetch(conn,sql_query);
result.(name)

ans =
   ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @tmpearce.  That works almost perfectly.  The onlu difference I made was to not include the parentheses around name.  When I did include them, I received an 'unexpected parentheses' error.  If I just wrote it as result.name, it works great!  Thanks again!